# List images matching a face

Tags: amazon-web-services, detection, face-recognition, face-detection

I am creating a application where users can scan their face and find all the images matching that face. I researched and tried but wasn't able to find a solution. Can anyone please help!! I am using amazon s3 for storing the images.

Comment: StackOverflow is generally not meant for opinion-based questions, like product recommendations. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: StackOverflow is generally not meant for opinion-based questions, like product recommendations. stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/what-is.html) has the ability to store faces and then search for a face amongst a [face collection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/collections.html).

It doesn't actually store the images. Rather, it stores attributes about the face that can be used to uniquely identify a face. Therefore, you would use the images to add the faces to the Face Collection, and then [Search for faces in an Amazon Rekognition collection using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/example_rekognition_SearchFaces_section.html).